# \ and $ character in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script:

```
text=test
echo "\Plugins\$text" is couting "\Plugins$text"
```

How to edit this command, so it displays `"\Plugins\test\`?

Comment: `echo "\Plugins\\\\${text}\\"`

Comment: You don't need to that many backslashes. `"\Plugins\\$text\\"` will suffice. (In fact, you are outputting an additional backslash not requested by the OP.)

Comment: Maybe there's some inconsistency across different shells, but this gives me `\Plugins est\`

Comment: @Greg That's due to the varying behavior of `echo`; the POSIX-specified behavior is to output the `\t` that `echo` sees *after* the shell has performed parameter interpolation as a literal tab character.

Comment: @0stone0's answer is for `zsh`. @chepner's answer is for `bash`.

Comment: What is "couting"?  `cout` is c++ 's name for "character output" as opposed to `wcout` which is "wide character output", neither of which is related to this question.  `couting` is not a verb, its a malapropism.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$text` is a parameter expansion, you need to escape the `$` to produce a literal `$`; that's what you are currently doing. You want a literal backslash instead; you need to escape the `\` itself.

You don't need to escape the initial backslash, because `\P` has no special meaning in a double-quoted string, and so a literal backslash is retained.

```
$ echo "\Plugins\\$text"
\Plugins\test
```

---

Because the behavior of `echo` can vary wildly from shell to shell in how it creates the resulting `\t`, it would be better to use `printf` for consistency.

```
$ printf '%s\n' "\Plugins\\$text"
\Plugins\test
```

Answer (score 1):

When the string can contain `\`, I would recommend `printf` over `echo`:

```bash
text=test
printf '"\\Plugins\\%s\\ is couting \\Plugins\\%s\\"\n' "$text" "$text"
```

```
"\Plugins\test\ is couting \Plugins\test\"
```